# Is it possible to map points from curve BN254 to C25519 and back using a 2-isogeny?

Tags: isogeny

If it is could you give me a paper that states it is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to map points from curve BN254 to C25519 and back using a 2-isogeny?

Those curves have different (relatively prime) orders, and so the only mapping from one curve to the other that preserves the group operation is the trivial one (map all points to the identity element), which is obviously not invertible.

Comment: Which Montogmery curve can you easily map to from BN254?

Comment: @Alex: BN254 has odd order; Montgomery curves always have an even order.  Now, you might be able to find a Montgomery curve that has a order that's a multiple of the BN254 order - you would map BN254 into a subgroup of the Montgomery curve.  However, I wouldn't know off the top how to do it (or if it is even feasible)

Comment: Is there a pairing-friendly curve and a Montgomery curve that can support a dual isogeny?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a curve that supports Montgomery ladders and pairing checks? 
Or, two curves that each support one or the other which can also support a dual isogeny?